# JSQMessagesViewController visible scrollToBottom on view entry

Tags: ios, swift, jsqmessagesviewcontroller

I am trying to create a simple messenger.

When messenger loads messages from cache (or from network), it calls `self.scrollToBottom(animated: false)` to show the most recent message, and it works, but I see a millisecond delay, like a blink.

How can I remove this delay? Can I set scroll position to the most recent message by default?

My code:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    ...

    VKApi()
    VKApi.messages(userId: userId, callback: {
        self.messages = $0 // Load messages
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            // When messages are set, scroll to bottom
            self.scrollToBottom(animated: false) 
        }

    })
    ...
}
```

Comment: what do you mean by a "millisecond delay, like a blink?" is the delay in "scrollToBottom" or for the completion handler to be called aka "async"

Comment: At slow-motion screen capture I see top message, then bottom one. The delay is between these operations